# Is click-lock flooring meant to be held down by baseboard?

Tags: flooring

I know that baseboard is used to cover the expansion gap when installing click lock flooring, but I'm wondering if part of its job is to actually prevent boards from lifting.

I recently installed click lock in one room. Leveled the floor, let the flooring acclimate, left an expansion gap, etc. But there is an area or two where, when you step on the floor, it dips a little. This is near a wall where I have not yet installed the base moulding.

Is it ok to push the floor down, install the moulding, and be done? Do I need to pull up the floor near there and shim?

Comment: Did you use underlayment?  Did you patch-level the sub floor before installing?

Comment: The subfloor was uneven gypcrete. Did a 4:1 redgard coat, then an undiluted coat, then self leveling primer, then self leveling, then 6mm cork.

Comment: If you use the molding to secure the flooring, it won't act as the required expansion gap.  Is the floor level in that area before you step on it or does it bend upward?  Does it become level when you step on it? Are the areas at the ends of some planks or along one of the faces?

Comment: There are two places, both near the end of planks by the wall. It gets level halfway between stepping it down.

Comment: Wasn't planning on securing the trim to it, just pinning the boards down with the trim (pushing down there trim, then nailing into the wall). Is that acceptable?